# Replacing a factor value in data frame by another value

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) with the following sample data:

```
          state.ut      district  year   AA        BB       CC
   1 ANDHRA PRADESH     ADILABAD  2001   50        30       16
   2 ANDHRA PRADESH     ANANTAPUR 2001   23        30       7
   3 ANDHRA PRADESH     CHITTOOR  2001   27        34       14
   4 ASSAM              GUWAHTI   2001   20        20       17
   5 ASSAM              JORHAT    2001   23        26       12
   6 DELHI              NEW DELHI 2001   10        20       23
```

I want to replace ANDHRA PRADESH, where ever it occurs in the data frame with Andhra Pradesh. ANDHRA PRADESH occurs at many places in the data frame but only in one column (state.ut) only but not in other columns.

The following R code gives an error:

```
> df$state.ut[df$state.ut=="ANDHRA PRADESH"]<-"Andhra Pradesh"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$state.ut == "ANDHRA PRADESH",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I am unable to understand the reason for error. Will be grateful for guidance.

Comment: Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[r]%20%22invalid%20factor%20level%2c%20NA%20generated%22) before asking.

Comment: I did search but I could not find answer to this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the relevant factor level directly, just need to figure out at which position it is in the vector of factor levels (here it is in position 1):

```
> levels(df$state.ut)
[1] "ANDHRA PRADESH" "ASSAM"          "DELHI"         
> levels(df$state.ut)[1] <- "Andrha Pradesh"
> df
        state.ut  district year AA BB CC
1 Andrha Pradesh  ADILABAD 2001 50 30 16
2 Andrha Pradesh ANANTAPUR 2001 23 30  7
3 Andrha Pradesh  CHITTOOR 2001 27 34 14
4          ASSAM   GUWAHTI 2001 20 20 17
5          ASSAM    JORHAT 2001 23 26 12
6          DELHI NEW DELHI 2001 10 20 23
```

Variables of class `factor` have a `levels` attribute, where the factors are stored (for example "Andra Pradesh" and "ASSAM"). You can look at the levels of a factor variable by using `levels()` on the variable. You can assign to that variable any of the levels that already defined but you cannot use a "new" (undefined) factor level. So in your case "Andra Pradesh" is such a new (undefined) factor level and you have to first tell R that this is now part of the factor levels. In fact it's a special case here because you want to *replace* all occurences of an existing factor level ("ANDRA PRADESH") with the new one. That's why you can simply replace the old factor level with the new one. Otherwise, you would have to define "Andra Pradesh" as an additional factor level.

Comment: Yes. It works. Kindly do explain a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: @user3282777, added an explanation. Please also read `?factor`.